# How to remove declaration that is defined in a global context?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using a typescript library `"typescript": "^3.6.0"` in my project.
This library "sort of" declares a variable named `origin`, which causes the following code to compile, but throw an exception on execution:

```
interface Props {
  otherProp: string;
  origin: string;
}

function runThis(props: Props) {
  const { otherProp } = props;
  return otherProp + origin;
}
```

The problems I have:

- This code fails on execution
- This is work on an existing code base, and I can't change the `origin` name without a massive change to the entire code base
- Fixing it locally will not prevent others from making this mistake when working on the same code base.

The solution I'm looking for: Remove declaration for `origin` from the global context.

Comment: You say that the code fails on execution, but also that it works in an existing code base. Which is it? Also, if you can't change the name `origin` without "a massive change to the entire code base", what makes you think you can remove it without a similar effort?

Comment: This is part of a refactoring effort during which I've used properties supplied by an existing interface. The interface is a given axiom, my code (and future code) are the variable. All existing code worked. The new code I added failed since I didn't extract `origin` but (after some debugging) understood I've used the global declaration

Answer (score -1):

I believe "origin" doesn't exist in your function. You are using object destructuring so I will try with:

```
interface Props {
  otherProp: string;
  origin: string;
}

function runThis(props: Props) {
  const { otherProp, origin } = props;
  return otherProp + origin;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. I want my code to not compile, since I want to protect the project from future errors. I came across this issue since this code compiled for me and it took me a while to understand where the problem was.